# Auto-generated POKey object in Intershop 7 compilation errors

Tags: orm, intershop

We are migrating site from Intershop 6.4 to Intershop 7.9.
As suggested by Intershop support, we are trying to recreate all the auto-generated classes from the EDL model.

Here is the interface EDL code:

```
import "enfinity:/core/edl/com/intershop/beehive/core/types.edl";
import "enfinity:/core/edl/com/intershop/beehive/core/capi/domain/PersistentObject.edl";
import "enfinity:/core/edl/com/intershop/beehive/core/capi/domain/PersistentObjectPO.edl";

external PromotionCollection type "java.util.Collection<A1Promotion>";

namespace hr.a1.core.capi.promotion
{
    cartridge interface A1Promotion extends PersistentObject
    {
        /**
         * Promotion TMCode.
         */
        attribute tmCode: string required;

        /**
         * Siebel promotion id.
         */
        attribute siebelID: string required;

        /**
         * Promotion name.
         */
        attribute name: string required;

        /**
         * Promotion description / currently URL to CW.
         */
        attribute description: string;

        /**
         * Defines promotion priority / lower values first.
         */
        attribute priority: int;

        /**
         * Holds link to tariff.
         */
        attribute tariffID: uuid;

        /**
         * Contract type (A, M, R).
         */
        attribute contractType: string required;

        /**
         * Contract binding (0, 12, 24).
         */
        attribute contractBinding: string required;

        /**
         * Discount type / MF - monthly fee, HW - hardware, FU - free unit (not used at the moment)
         */
        attribute discountType: string required;

        /**
         * Discount mode / P - percentage or F - fixed amount
         */
        attribute discountMode: string;

        /**
         * Discount amount / either money value or percentage value / stored internally as Money
         */
        attribute discountAmount: Money;

        /*
         * Flag which if it set disables checkbox of current promotion so user can't deselect it.
         */
        attribute preselected: boolean;

        /**
         * Promotion validity / from date.
         */
        attribute activeFrom: datetime;

        /**
         * Promotion validity / to date.
         */
        attribute activeTo: datetime;

        /**
         * Promotion group / D - default, N - personalized, S% - Special
         */
        attribute promotionGroup: string required;

         /**
         * Promotion type / S - single, G - group
         */
        attribute promotionType: string required;

        /**
         * Free units amount type (MB, GB, SMS..)
         */
        attribute units: string;

        /**
         * Group rule defined for promotion if promotion is group promotion
         */
        attribute groupRule: string;

        /**
         * Name of the coupon list for the coupon promotions
         */
        attribute couponListName: string;

        /**
         * HW promotion discount id
         */
        attribute discountId: int; 
    }

}
```

and this is the PO EDL code:

```
import "enfinity:/app_core_a1/edl/app_core_a1/capi/A1Promotion.edl";
import "enfinity:/xcs/edl/com/intershop/beehive/xcs/internal/product/ProductPO.edl";
import "enfinity:/core/edl/com/intershop/beehive/core/types.edl";
import "enfinity:/core/edl/com/intershop/beehive/core/capi/domain/PersistentObjectPO.edl";

namespace hr.a1.core.internal.promotion
{
    /*
     * @author dragisic
     */
    orm class A1PromotionPO extends PersistentObjectPO implements A1Promotion table "A1Promotion"
    {
        /**
         * Promotion id.
         */
        attribute tmCode : string<25> required column "tm_code";

        /**
         * Siebel promotion id.
         */
        attribute siebelID : string<25> required column "siebel_id";

        /**
         * Promotion name.
         */
        attribute name : string<100> required column "name";

        /**
         * Promotion description / currently URL to CW.
         */
        attribute description : string<255> column "description";

        /**
         * Defines promotion priority / lower values first.
         */
        attribute priority : int column "priority";

        /**
         * Holds link to tariff.
         */
        attribute tariffID : uuid;

        /**
         * Contract type (A, M, R).
         */
        attribute contractType : string<1> required column "contract_type";

        /**
         * Contract binding (0, 12, 24).
         */
        attribute contractBinding : string<4> required column "contract_binding";

        /**
         * Discount type / MF - monthly fee, HW - hardware, FU - free unit (not used at the moment)
         */
        attribute discountType : string<2> required column "discount_type";

        /**
         * Discount mode / P - percentage or F - fixed amount
         */
        attribute discountMode : string<1> column "discount_mode";

        /**
         * Discount amount / either money value or percentage value / stored internally as Money
         */
        attribute discountAmount : Money column "discount_amount";

        /**
         * Flag which if it set disables checkbox of current promotion so user can't deselect it.
         */
        attribute preselected : boolean column "is_preselected";

        /**
         * Promotion validity / from date.
         */
        attribute activeFrom : datetime column "active_from";

        /**
         * Promotion validity / to date.
         */
        attribute activeTo : datetime column "active_to";

        /**
         * Promotion group / D - default, N - personalized, S% - Special
         */
        attribute promotionGroup : string<3> required column "promo_group";

         /**
         * Promotion type / S - single, G - group
         */
         attribute promotionType : string<1> required column "promo_type";

        /**
         * Free units amount type (MB, SMS..)
         */
        attribute units : string<4> column "units";

        /**
         * Group rule defined for promotion if promotion is group promotion
         */
        attribute groupRule : string<10> column "group_rule";

        /**
         * Name of the coupon list for the coupon promotions
         */
         attribute couponListName: string<100> column "coupon_list_name";

         /**
         * Defines HW promotion discount id.
         */
        attribute discountId : int column "discount_id";

        /**
         * Declare index in search items.
         */
        index (contractType, contractBinding);
    }
}
```

However, when we generate the code with the "Code generator for Intershop version 7.2 and later" we get the following compilation errors in the auto-generated class A1PromotionPOKey.java:

"The constructor Object(String) is undefined"
"The hierarchy of the type A1PromotionPOKey is inconsistent"

The auto-generated class looks like this:

```
// =============================================================================
// File: A1PromotionPOKey.java
// Generated by JGen Code Generator from INTERSHOP Communications AG.
// Generator template: ORMKey.xpt(checksum: b5b09bf4e9329db7d7dafe870b159b0d)
// =============================================================================
// The JGen Code Generator software is the property of INTERSHOP Communications AG.
// Any rights to use are granted under the license agreement.
// =============================================================================
package hr.a1.core.internal.promotion;

import com.intershop.beehive.core.capi.domain.PersistentObjectPOKey;

/**
 * This class represents the primary key for objects of type A1PromotionPO.
 * The key objects can be used for lookup operations in the database.
 * 
 * @author dragisic
 * @generated
 */
public class A1PromotionPOKey extends PersistentObjectPOKey {
    /**
     * Useless constant to make compiler happy.
     *
     * @generated
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * Creates an empty primary key. After creation of a new key object
     * you must call the corresponding set<i>Attribute</i> method(s) to 
     * set the value(s) of the primary key.
     *
     * @generated
     */
    public A1PromotionPOKey() {
    }

    /**
     * Creates a primary key with the specified value(s).
     *
     * @generated
     */
    public A1PromotionPOKey(
        String UUID) {
        super(UUID);
    }

}
```

We have checked the gradle dependencies and the PersistentObjectPOKey import looks fine and the containing jar is added in the cartridge. We have also tried restarting Studio and refreshing the project, but it doesn't help.
Same EDL model works fine and produces compilable auto-generated code in Enfinity Suite 6.4.

EDIT:

Also, Im attaching errors from the console log during gradle build of the project.

```
:app_core_a1:compileJavaC:\Work\VIPnet\a1webshop\app_core_a1\src\main\java\hr\a1\core\internal\promotion\A1PromotionPOKey.java:20: error: cannot access CacheClearKey
public class A1PromotionPOKey extends
       ^
  class file for com.intershop.beehive.cache.capi.common.CacheClearKey not found
C:\Work\VIPnet\a1webshop\app_core_a1\src\main\java\hr\a1\core\capi\promotion\A1PromotionMgr.java:11: warning: [deprecation] Manager in com.intershop.beehive.core.capi.common has been deprecated
import com.intershop.beehive.core.capi.common.Manager;
                                             ^
C:\Work\VIPnet\a1webshop\app_core_a1\src\main\java\hr\a1\core\internal\promotion\A1PromotionPOFactory.java:14: warning: [deprecation] UUIDMgr in com.intershop.beehive.core.capi.util has been deprecated
import com.intershop.beehive.core.capi.util.UUIDMgr;
                                           ^
C:\Work\VIPnet\a1webshop\app_core_a1\src\main\java\hr\a1\core\capi\promotion\A1PromotionMgr.java:11: warning: [deprecation] Manager in com.intershop.beehive.core.capi.common has been deprecated
import com.intershop.beehive.core.capi.common.Manager;
                                             ^
C:\Work\VIPnet\a1webshop\app_core_a1\src\main\java\hr\a1\core\internal\promotion\A1PromotionPOFactory.java:14: warning: [deprecation] UUIDMgr in com.intershop.beehive.core.capi.util has been deprecated
import com.intershop.beehive.core.capi.util.UUIDMgr;
                                           ^
warning: The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[componentName]'
C:\Work\VIPnet\a1webshop\app_core_a1\src\main\java\hr\a1\core\capi\promotion\A1PromotionMgr.java:11: warning: [deprecation] Manager in com.intershop.beehive.core.capi.common has been deprecated
import com.intershop.beehive.core.capi.common.Manager;
                                             ^
C:\Work\VIPnet\a1webshop\app_core_a1\src\main\java\hr\a1\core\internal\promotion\A1PromotionPOFactory.java:14: warning: [deprecation] UUIDMgr in com.intershop.beehive.core.capi.util has been deprecated
import com.intershop.beehive.core.capi.util.UUIDMgr;
                                           ^
C:\Work\VIPnet\a1webshop\app_core_a1\src\main\java\hr\a1\core\capi\promotion\A1PromotionMgr.java:24: warning: [deprecation] Manager in com.intershop.beehive.core.capi.common has been deprecated
    Manager {
    ^
C:\Work\VIPnet\a1webshop\app_core_a1\src\main\java\hr\a1\core\internal\promotion\A1PromotionPO.java:120: error: incompatible types: A1PromotionPOKey cannot be converted to PersistentObjectPOKey
        super(factory, key);
                       ^
C:\Work\VIPnet\a1webshop\app_core_a1\src\main\java\hr\a1\core\internal\promotion\A1PromotionPOFactory.java:82: error: incompatible types: A1PromotionPOKey cannot be converted to ORMObjectKey
        A1PromotionPO instance = (A1PromotionPO) getEngine().getPersistenceManager().createObject(key, getClassDescription());
                                                                                                  ^
C:\Work\VIPnet\a1webshop\app_core_a1\src\main\java\hr\a1\core\internal\promotion\A1PromotionPOFactory.java:110: warning: [deprecation] UUIDMgr in com.intershop.beehive.core.capi.util has been deprecated
            UUIDMgr.getInstance().createUUIDString(), domain.getUUID(), tmCode, siebelID, name, contractType, contractBinding, discountType, promotionGroup, promotionType);
            ^
C:\Work\VIPnet\a1webshop\app_core_a1\src\main\java\hr\a1\core\internal\promotion\A1PromotionPOFactory.java:110: warning: [deprecation] getInstance() in UUIDMgr has been deprecated
            UUIDMgr.getInstance().createUUIDString(), domain.getUUID(), tmCode, siebelID, name, contractType, contractBinding, discountType, promotionGroup, promotionType);
                   ^
C:\Work\VIPnet\a1webshop\app_core_a1\src\main\java\hr\a1\core\internal\promotion\A1PromotionPOFactory.java:110: warning: [deprecation] createUUIDString() in UUIDMgr has been deprecated
            UUIDMgr.getInstance().createUUIDString(), domain.getUUID(), tmCode, siebelID, name, contractType, contractBinding, discountType, promotionGroup, promotionType);
                                 ^
C:\Work\VIPnet\a1webshop\app_core_a1\src\main\java\hr\a1\core\internal\promotion\A1PromotionPOFactory.java:149: error: incompatible types: A1PromotionPOKey cannot be converted to ORMObjectKey
        return (A1PromotionPO) super.getObjectByPrimaryKeyObject(key);
                                                                 ^
C:\Work\VIPnet\a1webshop\app_core_a1\src\main\java\hr\a1\core\internal\promotion\A1PromotionPOFactory.java:178: error: incompatible types: A1PromotionPOKey cannot be converted to ORMObjectKey
        return (A1PromotionPO) super.getObjectByPrimaryKeyObject(key, mode);
```

Comment: The _ORMObjectKey_ class implements the _CacheClearKey_ interface which is located within the 'cache' component. This interface is not found while you compile the _A1PromotionPOKey_ class. Please check if the 'cache' component is part of your dependencies:

        compile group: 'com.intershop.platform', name: 'cache'

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now.
Just one more question. I noticed that the code generator didn't automatically generate MgrImpl classes anymore as it used to with version 6.4. Does it mean we should generate *Impl classes manually now or we are doing something wrong?

Comment: The 'Application Programming Guide' (6.4) page 75 says: _Although possible from a technical point of view, Intershop itself does not model the Enfinity Suite manager interfaces and their respective implementing classes any longer._ (Paragraph 'Modeling of Managers and the respective Implementations'). I do not remember manager code generation at all.

Comment: So, if I got you right, we should generate Mgr interface and MgrImpl manually or we shouldnt implement it at all and use BOs instead? Cookbooks on Intershop support are really unclear on the use of managers. There are still 7.9 cookbooks in which it is explained that Mgr.edl should be used, like this one:
https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/A23274